# numpy get std between datasets

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset array `A`. `A` is `n`×`2`. It can be plotted on the x and y axis.
`A[:,1]` gets me all of the Y values ans `A[:,0]` gets me all the x values.

Now, I have a few other dataset arrays that are similar to `A`. X values are the same for these similar arrays. How do I calculate the standard deviation of the datasets? There should be a std value for each X. In the end my result `std` should have a length of `n`.

I can do this the manual way with loops but I'm not sure how to do this using NumPy in a pythonic and simple manner.

here are some sample data:

```
A=[[0,2.54],[1,254.5],[2,-43]]
B=[[0,3.34],[1,154.5],[2,-93]]
std_Array=[std(2.54,3.54),std(254.5,154.5),std(-43,-93)]
```

Comment: You should post some sample data, input and expected output. You say your result should be length n, is that because there are n arrays? Is this the same n as the length of A. Do you just want the std of the x-values from each array. If you have a list of the arrays you can use `np.dstack` to make a 3D array and then take the std. along the appropriate axis

Comment: np.std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=False) with ddof=0 is the population st. dev...with ddof=1, it is the sample std dev.  do be aware that if you have NaNs, there is an equivalent np.nanstd with the similar ddof options

Answer (score 0):

Is this pythonic enough?

```
std_Array = numpy.std((A,B), axis = 0)[:,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your arrays are all the same shape and they are in a list. Then to get the standard deviation of the first column of each you can do

```
arrays = [np.random.rand(10, 2) for _ in range(8)]
np.dstack(arrays).std(axis=0)[0]
```

This stacks the 2-D arrays into a 3-D array an then takes the `std` along the first axis, giving a 2 X 8 (the number of arrays). The first row of the result is the std. devs. of the 8 sets of x-values. 
If you post some sample data perhaps we could help more.

Answer (score 0):

```
li_arr = [np.array(x)[: , 1]  for x in [A , B]]
```

This will produce numpy arrays with specifi columns you want to add the result will be

```
[array([   2.54,  254.5 ,  -43.  ]), array([   3.34,  154.5 ,  -93.  ])]
```

then you stack the values using `column_stack`

```
arr = np.column_stack(li_arr)
```

this will be the result stacking

```
array([[   2.54,    3.34],
       [ 254.5 ,  154.5 ],
       [ -43.  ,  -93.  ]])
```

and then finally

```
np.std(arr , axis = 1)
```